# How do I change PPPoE password on Windows XP?

Tags: windows-xp, networking, passwords, dsl, pppoe

My mother has managed to change her DSL PPPoE password on the ISP side, but doesn't know how to change it on the XP side.  I tried for a half hour over the phone to find it (remote assistance didn't work), but I haven't had a PPPoE connection in about 10 years so I didn't come up with anything.  Google only managed to find me ways to create a new connection, not modify an existing one.  There isn't a 3rd party connection program in play here, starting Firefox is enough to initiate the connection.

How do I change the password stored on XP for a PPPoE connection?  The modem is connected directly to the computer, no router.  Its an AT&T DSL line, but I doubt that matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Start** > **Control Panel** >  **Network Connections**

There should be a connection listed under **Broadband** (connection name / status / WAN Miniport / PPPOE)

[image]

Double click to open the **Connect dialog**:

[image]

Make sure to enter the correct user name and password, then click **Connect**. Windows will "remember" the settings if the box **Save this user name and password for the following users** is checked.